# Create function for constructor of generic class

Tags: typescript

Consider this:

```
export class Method<TBody extends Body = Body, TResponse extends Response = Response, TQuery extends z.Shape = z.Shape> {
  constructor(
    readonly method: "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "DELETE",
    readonly options: {
      readonly summary?: string;
      readonly query?: TQuery;
      readonly body?: TBody;
      readonly response: TResponse;
    },
  ) {}
}
```

How can I create a factory function without specifying all generic types again?

```
export function method<T extends any[]>(...args: T) {
  return new Method(...args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the helper type [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype):

```
export function method(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Method>): Method {
  return new Method(...args);
}
```

Comment: That doesn’t expose the generics of Method

Comment: Oh OK I misunderstood your question, well you can't do that